# Is it possible to open WMC(Web map Context) file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wmc

I am new to WMC and in our application we had a requirement to extend the WMC functions.

For that I need to know whether QGIS have the support of WMC files.

Or we need any plugins for WMC support in the QGIS.

Is WMC (wmc.xml) files able to open in QGIS as like in the below link in OpenLayers
[OpenLayers WMC example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/wmc.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it is currently possible.

There is an open feature request for such functionality: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11018

Comment: Still not possible in QGIS 3.0